# How to bring the Brand to the center of Navbar using Bootstrap only when the hamburger menu shows up?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the name/logo of my brand appear in the center of the Navbar only when the screen is narrow enough to replace the links with the hamburger menu. In other words, the same behaviour of Apple website's Navbar.

The behaviour I'm expected to deliver is that the navbar should show the brand on the left side on normal web browsers, and once used on a phone or a mobile device, the logo should be in the center and the hamburger button should show on the left side. 
I'm using Bootstrap to implement that, so far I could bring the menu to the left, but I can't figure out how to center the brand ONLY when the links from the navbar are grouped in the hamburger menu

My HTML so far is as follows:

```
   <!DOCTYPE=HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <a href="https:/www.login-master.com" class="navbar-brand">MyBrand</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">User Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Selbstverwaltung</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Einstellungen</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Abmelden</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">   </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```

My css:

```
    /*COLORING THE NAVBAR GREEN*/
.navbar-default
{
    background-color: #199fa0;
}

/*CHANGING THE FONT COLOUR OF THE NAVBAR BUTONS*/
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a
{
    color: #fff
}

/*CHANGING THE COLOUR OF THE HAMBURGER BUTTON*/
.icon-bar 
{
   background-color:#fff !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand
{
    color: #fff;
}

/*BRINGING THE HAMBURGER MENU BUTTON TO THE LEFT SIDE*/
.navbar-toggle 
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add following code to your css

```
a.navbar-brand {
float: none;
display: table;
margin: auto;
}
```

```css
    /*COLORING THE NAVBAR GREEN*/
.navbar-default
{
    background-color: #199fa0;
}

/*CHANGING THE FONT COLOUR OF THE NAVBAR BUTONS*/
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a
{
    color: #fff
}

/*CHANGING THE COLOUR OF THE HAMBURGER BUTTON*/
.icon-bar 
{
   background-color:#fff !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand
{
    color: #fff;
}

/*BRINGING THE HAMBURGER MENU BUTTON TO THE LEFT SIDE*/
.navbar-toggle 
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 14px;
}

a.navbar-brand {
    float: none;
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE=HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <a href="https:/www.login-master.com" class="navbar-brand">MyBrand</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">User Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Selbstverwaltung</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Einstellungen</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Abmelden</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">   </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the code to your css, the `@media (max-width: 768px)` means that it will only apply for small devices, when the hamburger menu appears.

```css
@media (max-width: 768px)
.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}


}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

        <a href="https:/www.login-master.com" class="navbar-brand">MyBrand</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">User Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Selbstverwaltung</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Einstellungen</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Abmelden</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"> </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
        {

```
        .navbar-default .navbar-brand
        {
            width: calc( 100% - 44px );
            width: -webkit-calc( 100% - 100px );
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            padding-right: 50px;
        }
    }
```